# AMD graphic driver reinstall fail [sort of SOLVED]

Tags: amd-graphics, amdgpu-pro

I have bought a Lenovo V130 with a graphic card AMD Radeon 530 2G. I put an Ubuntu 18.04 on it, updated, upgraded, then installed the driver from the AMD site (amdgpu-pro-18.20-673703-ubuntu-18.04). 
Of course, I met the login loop as it did crash with the integrated Intel Graphics. 
I used the

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```

command, then I could use the graphic mode again. Since then, when I wanted to reinstall the package, I get the error massage:

```
[sudo] m jelszava: 
deb [ trusted=yes ] file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/ ./
Letöltés:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Mellőz:1 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ InRelease
Letöltés:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Letöltés:2 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release [816 B]
Letöltés:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Mellőz:3 file:/var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local ./ Release.gpg
Találat:4 http://repo.jztkft.hu/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Találat:5 http://repo.jztkft.hu/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
Találat:6 http://repo.jztkft.hu/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Találat:7 http://repo.jztkft.hu/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Találat:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Csomaglisták olvasása... Kész 
Package: *amdgpu*
Pin: release o=AMD
Pin: version *-673703
Pin-Priority: 1000

Package: *amdgpu*:i386
Pin: release o=AMD
Pin: version *-673703
Pin-Priority: 1000

Csomaglisták olvasása... Kész
Függőségi fa építése       
Állapotinformációk olvasása... Kész
E: Ez a csomag nem található: xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-amdgpu-pro
```

Sorry, dont know how to set to English.
Letöltés = Download
Mellőz= Skip or Dispense
Találat= Found

At the end it says:
This package cannot be found: xserver-xorg-video-modesetting-amdgpu-pro

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, 18.04 of course, but I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Update

I deleted the amd folders from var/opt and usr/bin.
After that, I was able to install the driver, now the '17 version with --px. Everything worked well, there was not any login loop or black screen.

Still, in system information Ubuntu sees the Intel HD Graphics and its driver.
Can I check if there is a Radeon Card in my computer without disassembing it?

Answer (score 1):

So I worked it out.

Did these steps

```
$ sudo amdgpu-pro-uninstall

$ sudo apt-get autoremove amdgpu*
```

Manually deleted all amdgpu dependencies from `var/opt` and `usr/bin`

```
$ sudo apt update
```

Then I restarted the computer - for the sake of the piece of my hobby-linux soul - and followed the instructions on
https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers
I think I should have started here.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers

$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Restart again.

Since then, sys info says Mesa is running on my Ubuntu, instead of the Intel driver. Not really sure that it uses the Radeon card, though. How could I check it?